# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword AS

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run a query on Big Query but I keep getting the following error message; "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword AS"

Any comment on how this can be resolved will be much appreciated. Attached below is a screenshot of the error message and the query
[Big Query Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp7SJ.png)

I tried to run a query that I got from a data analytics course that I am studying. But I keep getting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in line 4 when you write

```
SELECT 

warehouse.state.

FROM
```

Remove dot in the end or correct the column name which you want to select.

Because of this dot, BiqQuery thinks thats you want to select smth with complex name:

```
SELECT warehouse.state.from`yourtable` as
```